# On tab press call custom function using jquery

Tags: jquery

I am trying to create a simple way to insert golf scores into a database.  I want to use jquery to make it nice and user friendly.  I don't have to worry about anyone not having js enabled as I will be the only using it.

I have created a test page you can go to look at what i have so far here,

www.barriemenshockey.com/testing/index.php

[Score Entry](http://www.barriemenshockey.com/testing/index.php)

Basically I have what I want when the user(me) clicks on a cell, everything works great.  But I want to be able to press tab and go to the next hole, type a number hit tab again to go to the next hole and so on.  Hopefully this makes sense.

Here is the JS I have so far:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var tabindex = 1;

$(document).ready(function()
{
    //on click
    $("div").click(function() 
    {        
        dowork($(this));   
    });

    $().keypress(function(event)
    {
        if (event.keyCode == 9)
        {
            var temp = $("#"+tabindex);
            dowork(temp);
            $("#10").html(tabindex);   
        }
    });
});

function dowork(ob)
{
    var number = $(ob).text(); 
    $(ob).empty();
    $(ob).append($("<input size=\'2\' style=\'border: none; text-align:center;\'>"));
    $(ob).find("input").focus(); 
    var input = $(ob).find("input");      

    input.blur(function(e) 
    { 
        //return it to its last known number
        if (input.val() == "") 
            input.val(number);
        else
            tabindex++;

        //remove the input html from the div
        var last = input.val();
        $(ob).html(last); 
    });         
}
</script>
```

And the structure is like this:

```
<table width="50%" border="1" align="center" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
      <tr>
          <td>1</td>
          <td>2</td>
          <td>3</td>
          <td>4</td>
          <td>5</td>
          <td>6</td>
          <td>7</td>
          <td>8</td>
          <td>9</td>
          <td>Out</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
          <td><div id="1">&nbsp;</div></td>
          <td><div id="2">7</div></td>
          <td><div id="3">&nbsp;</div></td>
          <td><div id="4">&nbsp;</div></td>
          <td><div id="5">&nbsp;</div></td>
          <td><div id="6">&nbsp;</div></td>
          <td><div id="7">&nbsp;</div></td>
          <td><div id="8">&nbsp;</div></td>
          <td><div id="9">&nbsp;</div></td>
          <td><div id="out">0</div></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
          <td>10</td>
          <td>11</td>
          <td>12</td>
          <td>13</td>
          <td>14</td>
          <td>15</td>
          <td>16</td>
          <td>17</td>
          <td>18</td>
          <td>In</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
          <td><div id="10">&nbsp;</div></td>
          <td><div id="11">&nbsp;</div></td>
          <td><div id="12">&nbsp;</div></td>
          <td><div id="13">&nbsp;</div></td>
          <td><div id="14">&nbsp;</div></td>
          <td><div id="15">&nbsp;</div></td>
          <td><div id="16">&nbsp;</div></td>
          <td><div id="17">&nbsp;</div></td>
          <td><div id="18">&nbsp;</div></td> 
          <td><div id="in">0</div></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
          <td colspan="9">&nbsp;</td>
          <td><div id="total">0</div></td>
      </tr>
  </table>
```

Thanks for the help.

Nick

Comment: I think I have to bind the keypress tab event to the blur event but have no clue where to start to do that.

Answer (score 1):

The events attached to input need to be attached via jQuery's live() function, since your inputs are dynamically added to the dom.

http://api.jquery.com/live/

**EDIT: Here's a working solution for you.**

```
$("div").click(function() {
            $div = $(this)
            var number = $div.text();
            $div.empty();
            $div.append("<input size=\'2\' style=\'border: none; text-align:center;\'>");
            $div.find('input').focus().val(number);
        });

        $('input').live('keydown',function(event) {
            var keycode = event.keyCode;
            if (keycode == 9) {
                var $div = $(this).parent();
                var nextID = parseInt($div.attr('id')) + 1;
                $div.html($(this).val());
                $('#' + nextID).click();
                event.preventDefault();
            }   
        });
```

Comment: I tried added the live event instead but got the same result.

Comment: +1. This works. Make sure to surround with  `$(document).ready(function(){});` or it fails of course.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the [.blur jquery event](http://api.jquery.com/blur/) to hook into when the text box loses focus. This would work regardless of whether you tab, click, etc.

In terms of the tab, you can specify tab order in the input tag, such as:

```
<input id="hole1" tabindex="1" />
<input id="hole2" tabindex="2" />
....
```

This will control where the cursor goes when the user tabs. Combine the two ideas above and you should be good to go..

Comment: Yes but when I press tab I need it to focus on the next div which creates the input.  Right now when I tab it tries to find the next tabindex element, whihc seems to be the address bar.

Comment: Good point. I was thinking the inputs were all present. You may need to hook into the keypress for tab then? You could detect which div it came from and fire the jquery to append the next input, focus it, etc.

Comment: That is my plan but from some reason I am having trouble retrieving the next id.  If you look at my structure up top you can see its pretty simple.  If i click on the hole 1 cell when I tab it should go to the next one.

Answer (score 0):

have you tried adding an

```
event.preventDefault();
```

in here:

```
if (event.keyCode == 9)
        {
            event.preventDefault();
            var temp = $("#"+tabindex);
            dowork(temp);
            $("#10").html(tabindex);   
        }
```